# Erro no build ionic framework

Tags: javascript, bash, terminal

Senhores, eu migrei pro linux e estou com uma dúvida/problema.

Eu já tenho o android sdk instalado com suas respectivas dependências instaladas, eu rodo o comando android e me abre o sdk manager normalmente, coloquei as variáveis de ambiente no arquivo `.zshrc` (mesmo que .bash_profile):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

E mesmo assim, quando vou rodar o ionic build android, eu recebo a mensagem que está na foto. Estou me esquecendo de algo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

As configurações das variáveis de ambiente foram feitas no perfil de seu usuário e não no perfil de root? Se sim você deve utilizar o comando: `ionic build android` com seu usuário e não como root!

Answer (score 0):

Como o Thyago falou, se você setou a variavel de ambiente do android no seu usuário, não precisa utilizar o `sudo`.

Lembrando que pra você gerar o apk do android o processo deve ser feito na seguinte ordem.

-Instalar o android studio

-Setar a variavel de ambiente do android, o *ANDROID_HOME*

-Ir no diretório do seu projeto e inserir o comando `ionic platform add android`

-Inserir o comando *ionic build android*